# Was Jeremiah questioning God's faithfulness in Jeremiah 15:18?

Tags: jeremiah

Jeremiah 15 NASB

> [16]Your words were found and I ate them, And Your words became for me a joy and the delight of my heart; For I have been called by Your name, O Lord God of hosts.

After praising God for his words that had brought him joy and delight suddenly Jeremiah seems to go at a tangent.

Jeremiah 15 NASB

> [18]Why has my pain been perpetual And my wound incurable, refusing to be healed? ***Will You indeed be to me like a deceptive stream With water that is unreliable***?

In the midst of such praise what had brought about this sudden change?

Was Jeremiah suddenly doubting God's faithfulness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Jeremiah is questioning the integrity and the source giver of his prophetic prophecies concerning himself. Not because he is accurate but because he assumed incorrectly.

Jeremiah is conflicted because he had certain expectations concerning the constant afflictions and reproach he bore from the people. Yet he reflects on the promise/s made to him and also on his experiences of being in the divine council.

V16 affirms that he is convinced he heard from Adonai and that he has a calling upon his life but the realities he is experiencing then conflicts with other prophetic words he heard

> “ADONAI said, “I promise to release you for good, I promise to make your enemies appeal to you when calamity and trouble come.”
>   ‭‭Yirmeyahu (Jer)‬ ‭15:11‬ ‭CJB‬‬

Jeremiah was not seeing this fulfilled and struggled to understand his pain and perpetual wound caused by his enemies. He finds himself between the promise given and the promise fulfilled and assumed that the period in between was the same as the finality. In his assumption he questions the integrity of Adonai because he overlooks certain details in the prophecy. This is then corrected.

> “This is ADONAI ’s answer: “If you return — if I bring you back — you will stand before me. If you separate the precious from the base, you will be my spokesman. It will then be they who turn to you, not you who turn to them.”
>   ‭‭Yirmeyahu (Jer)‬ ‭15:19‬ ‭CJB‬‬

The issue was not that Adonai was being deceptive it was that Jeremiah assumed that the journey would be the same as the fulfillment of the journey/prophecy and he overlooked the fact that the prophecy had details in it, which did not give him that false assurance he assumed. The prophecy did not say what he understood (or wanted it to mean).

The deception lies with Jeremiah. He deceived himself by assuming certain aspects and in doing so “he laid down in torment” as Isaiah puts it. He was conflicted in his mind, fortunately Adonai’s compassion realigned Jetemiah’s understanding to reflect the truth and not the implied assumptions that came with the prophecy, which was Jeremiah’s doing. He lit up his own lights in the darkness, that was not illuminated for him to see. Worst he claimed that it was Adonai who gave him light for that period but that period was shrouded in darkness by Adonai. Jeremiah attributes light to it for himself.

> “Who among you fears ADONAI? Who obeys what his servant says? Even when he walks in the dark, without any light, he will trust in ADONAI ’s reputation and rely on his Maker. But all of you who are lighting fires and arming yourselves with firebrands: go, walk in the flame of your own fire, among the firebrands you lit! From my hands this [fate] awaits you: you will lie down in torment.”
>   ‭‭Yesha 'yahu (Isa)‬ ‭50:10-11‬ ‭CJB‬‬

The lesson here is clear. If you have not received light about something, don’t light your own light or you will be tormented mentally. That’s why Jeremiah is conflicted and begins to doubt the source of his revelations, failing to realize he added his reasonings and lit up his own light for the part that was still masked and in darkness. The part that was in the light (prophesied) had not yet come, so in the mean time it was not unacceptable that Jeremiah be in pain and wounded. Adonai did not promise hdim what he assumed.