# Looking for passage in Jeremaiah about keeping faith

Tags: faith

I vaguely remember a passage in Jeremiah where God tells Jeremiah something along the lines "if you keep faith in the words I give you to say, I will protect you from your enemies, but if you loose faith I will forsake you". Is there such a passage? I can't find it now.

Comment: Please take the tour below and familiarize yourself with acceptable questions and criteria to asking said question. The passage you are probably looking for is in Jeremiah 15, maybe it’s verse 11 but there is a bigger context to that verse which Jeremiah misunderstood. Please check this question and see if it answers yours https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38097/was-jeremiah-questioning-gods-faithfulness-in-jeremiah-1518/38109#38109 welcome to Hermeneutics Stack.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Questions about "find me a text" are not welcome.  Use a good concordance or on0line search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely referring to the end of Jeremiah chapter 1.